# when countdown meets its condition then i need setstate ::::::::TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting error after countdown time `TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Item extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         redirect:false
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
       // THIS IS THE TIMER CODE
       setInterval(function() {
        var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
        var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
        div.textContent = count;
        if (count <= 0) {
            this.setState({redirect:true})
            // window.location.replace("https://example.com");

        }
    }, 1000);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="counter">10</div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

export default Item

Comment: Declare setTimeout as an arrow function to achieve function binding

Comment: Since your function is not an arrow function, then `this` doesn't refer to class component, you can switch your defined function in setInterval callback to an arrow function. like this: `setInterval(() => {// your code}, 1000);`